# How to start a systemd service based on ExecStartPre execution result

Tags: linux, debian, systemd

I have a daemon which is started using systemd service file during boot-up flow.
I want to start the daemon based on the execution result of a script. **The script is included in service file under ExecStartPre option**.

> Based on the **execution result of the script**, I have to handle the service as mentioned below

1. If the script returns **0, start the service and proceed with bootup**
2. If **1** is returned, **stop the service, don't proceed with bootup**
3. If **2** is returned, **don't start the service but proceed with bootup**

I would like to know whether my scenario is valid. If yes how to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

`systemd.service(5)` says:

> ```
>   ExecStartPre=, ExecStartPost=
>       Additional commands that are executed before or after the command in
>       ExecStart=, respectively. Syntax is the same as for ExecStart=, except that
>       multiple command lines are allowed and the commands are executed one after the
>       other, serially.
>
>       If any of those commands (not prefixed with "-") fail, the rest are not
>       executed and the unit is considered failed.
>
>       ExecStart= commands are only run after all ExecStartPre= commands that were not
>       prefixed with a "-" exit successfully.
> ```

So you can use a non-zero exit code to fail the service.  This satisfies requirements 1 & 3 on your list.  This means if `ExecStartPre=` returns 0, the service starts and everything continues to boot.  If `ExecStartPre=` does not return 0, the service is flagged as failed and everything else continues to boot.  If you call `systemctl status`, you'll see `State: degraded`.

Condition 2 is a bit confusing.  By "don't proceed with bootup" do you either mean "shutdown" or "systemctl stop multi-user.target"?  If this service fails to start, you might just shut down the system, and never be able to log-in to solve the problem (unless you enter some type of rescue mode).  Regardless of how to stop `multi-user.target` or start `shutdown.target`, it's not something you can easily do based on the exit code of an `ExecStartPre=`.  You'd need to replace your `ExecStartPre=` with a shell script which calls the original line, and deals with the exit code.

I suspect that you might want something like `Restart=on-failure` instead.  The service can be restarted (or a restart can be prevented) based on the exit code of the main process using `RestartForceExitStatus=` or `RestartPreventExitStatus=`