# Run systemd service only if script condion is True

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, systemd-journald

I have a systemd service that writes to a LCD screen as below;

```
[Unit]
Description=LCD Screen


[Service]
Type=simple
User=admin
WorkingDirectory=/lcd
ExecStart=sudo /run_lcd.py
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=lcd-service
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I only want the service to run if the LCD screen is connected to the machine. Since the panel is connected via a serial port the only way to know is to send a specific message to the LCD screen which will, if connected, return a value. If I run this in a script is there a way to get the output of the script and have the service run according to the output?

I've looked at the [conditions and asserts in systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conditions%20and%20Asserts) but it doesn't show an option to do what I want to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See `man systemd.service` , `ExecStartPre` https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=

Comment: try creating something like lock file when the screen is connected and then use `ConditionPathExists=¶` ... https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#ConditionPathExists=

Comment: Related: [How to start a systemd service based on ExecStartPre execution result](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597119/how-to-start-a-systemd-service-based-on-execstartpre-execution-result)

Comment: @Panki, this doesn't stop the service from restarting when  `ExecStartPre` fails though. Is there a way to do something like `ConditionPathExists` but with running a script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Edgar's answer, `ExecStartPre=` isn't bad, but if it blocks execution of your `ExecStart=`, your service is marked `failed`.

You could also try `ExecCondition=`.  The behavior is like an `ExecStartPre=` and `Condition*=` hybrid.

| Exit code | Behaviour |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Unit continues starting |
| 1-254 | Start is abandoned, unit goes `inactive (dead)` |
| 255 | Start is abandoned, unit becomes `failed` |

Here's a simple example:

```
$ cat condition.service 
[Service]
ExecCondition=/bin/false
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 20

$ systemctl --user start  condition.service
$ systemctl --user status condition.service
● condition.service
     Loaded: loaded 
     Active: inactive (dead)

Starting condition.service...
condition.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
condition.service: Skipped due to 'exec-condition'.
```

---

Your `restart=always` poses a problem.  If `ExecCondition=` inhibits startup, it will just try again... forever...  (`RestartSec=` prevents it from hitting the start limit).  This probably isn't what you want.

I would use `restart=on-failure`.  If your service returns `EXIT_SUCCESS`, then it probably finished its work and you probably don't need to ask it to do the job again.  However, if it encounters an error, it can always `return EXIT_FAILURE;` to be restarted.   `ExecCondition=` makes this possible.

With `ExecStartPre=`, your service exits with a failure if your script tries to inhibit the service.  This means `restart=on-failure` would not be available to you, and `restart=on-success` or `restart=no` are your only options.

---

A few other tips:

- `User=admin`

  - You are using `sudo` in scripts.  Not only does this rely on `NOPASSWD:` in your sudoers, but it also elevates `admin` to `root`.  If you really need root permissions to run this script, then just run the service directly as root and delete this line.
- `ExecStart=sudo /run_lcd.py`

  - `run_lcd.py` shouldn't nomally be installed to `/`.  If this is a script you wrote (or manually installed), put it in `/usr/local/bin`.  Being organized like this really helps you to find "all local stuff" when it is time to re-create your server on new hardware.
- `Type=simple`

  - I suppose it never hurts to be explicit, but this is the default value of `Type=`.  I wouldn't bother adding this as it just clutters the file.
- `Standard{Output,Error}=syslog`

  - The `syslog` option has been removed from systemd.  It might still work for backwards compatibility, but it has been removed from [the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=).  Remove this line to use the journal per defaults (it will be forwarded as appropriate).  The documentation (checked debian buster) used to say:

  > **syslog** connects standard output to the syslog(3) system syslog
  > service, in addition to the journal. Note that the journal daemon
  > is usually configured to forward everything it receives to syslog
  > anyway, in which case this option is no different from journal.
- `RestartSec=10`

  - This is a bit of a hack people use to avoid hitting the restart limit.  It's particularly useful to people who have graphical applications start after `multi-user.target` is raised.  A better solution is to start your unit only after its resources are all ready.  Using `WantedBy=graphical.target` is often the correct solution.  `After=graphical.target` can also work to ensure a service doesn't start until after things are ready.  Since your service seems related to graphics, I suspect these will help.  Regardless, once you finally have a well-behaved service, `RestartSet=` should be unnecessary.

---

Putting it together I would use:

```
[Unit]
Description=LCD Screen
After=graphical.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/lcd
ExecCondition=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/checkScreen.py
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/run_lcd.py
SyslogIdentifier=lcd-service
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Comment: Excellent answer; the only other thing I'd add, given the (good) suggestion to move the script to /usr/local, is -- **if** /usr/local is a separate filesystem -- then to add an `After=local-fs.target` dependency, to ensure this service isn't started until its filesystem is mounted.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to change `Restart=always` to `Restart=on-success` and as @Panki said you should use `ExecStartPre`.

So I recommend you use another script (I assume in python) to check if the screen is connected, for example a simple python script would be:

**/checkScreen.py**

```py
#you will have to add before this lines the code
#used for getting the status of screen

if screenIsConnected:
    exit(0)
else:
    exit(1)
```

Your systemd service would become:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=LCD Screen

[Service]
Type=simple
User=admin
WorkingDirectory=/lcd
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/python3 /checkScreen.py
ExecStart=sudo /run_lcd.py
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=lcd-service
Restart=on-success
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```